# Bidirectional LSTM: Accuracy starts at 1% and decreases to 0.01%

Tags: python, keras, lstm

```
def cus_gen(batch_size,X,y):
    while True:
        X,y=shuffle(X,y)
        for i in range(len(X)//batch_size):
            yield (numpy.array(X[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]),numpy.array(y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]))



optimizer=adam(lr=0.001)

model=Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=733,output_dim=60,input_length=12))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(250,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'),merge_mode='concat'))
Dropout(0.4)

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(350,return_sequences=True,activation='relu'),merge_mode='concat'))
Dropout(0.4)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(332, activation='sigmoid')))
model.compile(loss='cosine_proximity',optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['acc'])
model.fit_generator(generator=cus_gen(40,X,y),steps_per_epoch=10000,epochs=100)
```

Is there anything I can tweak? I tried different optimizers, different batch sizes non seem to work.!

Its a confidential project, I cant reveal the data set.

Comment: I tweaked Dropout to 0.2 and decreased embedding output to 40. It seems it improved.

Comment: What is the task? What are you trying to achieve with this model?